# Download YouTube video from web service

Tags: youtube

Is there any website offers YouTube video downloads via web service or just produces a downloadable link from YouTube URL?

Answer (score 5):

I use [SaveYouTube.com](http://www.saveyoutube.com/) for that purpose. Given any YouTube video link, this service produces the video and audio (direct download) links.

Let's say you want to download a YouTube video which has the following link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUfBJrnrPNg

In your browser's address bar, put the word "save" just before "youtube", and this takes you directly to the download page:  http://www.saveyoutube.com/watch?v=uUfBJrnrPNg

Comment: I've used other websites to do this, but being able to just type "save" to redirect is an awesome feature. Thanks for the tip!